# Pass arguments to saga dispatch - and get the argument to the handler

Tags: redux-saga

This is my saga right now:

```
function* upAsyncSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(UP_ASYNC, upAsyncHandler);
}
```

And here is the related sync material:

```
const UP_ASYNC = 'UP_ASYNC';
export function upAsync() {
    return {
        type: UP_ASYNC
    }
}
function* upAsyncHandler() {
    yield call(wait, 1000);
    yield put(up());
}

const UP = 'UP';
export function up() {
    return {
        type: UP
    }
}
```

I trigger the `upAsyncSaga` by doing this `store.dispatch(upAsync())`. However I want to pass an argument called `times`. So I want to do `store.dispatch(upAsync(3))` and then *i hope/want to* get the argument to the handler like this pseudocode:

```
export function upAsync(times) { // this is the argument "times"
    return {
        type: UP_ASYNC
        times // here it is again
    }
}
function* upAsyncHandler(times) { // i want the argument to get to the handler
    for (let i=0; i<times; i++) {
        yield call(wait, 1000);
        yield put(up());
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we dispatch any action to store, we can include the arguments (payload) like this:

```
store.dispatch( { type: UP_ASYNC, payload : { times: 2 }})
```

modify your function:

```
export function upAsync(type, payload) {
  const { type, times } = payload
    return {
        type: type,
        times: times
    }
}
```

I am unsure how your full store implementation is, but if you are following redux-saga, the above should fix you problem.

Edit:

If you have redux store which has effects (I believe), then you can simply execute an action like this:

```
dispatch({type: '<namespace>/upAsyncHandler', payload: {type: UP_ASYNC, times: 2}})
```

Here, 'namespace' means your namespace in redux store where your handler is defined as an effect. See below:

```
*upAsynHandler(action, { call }) {
  const { type, times } = action
  const res = yield call(wait, times)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Umesh, but how can I get that `payload` to `upAsyncHandler`?

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally understand now. Please excuse my delay in accepting your solution.

Comment: Not working. `action` is `undefined`.
Your solution is valid only if you do not use root saga. It is wrong for root saga set up

Comment: @Green, this is proven and used solution, please think before your downvote

Answer (score 1):

When calling dispatch, the action will be passed to the handler.

```js
function* myFn(action){
  const {type, counter} = action
  console.log(counter) // 0
}

function* mySaga() {
  yield effects.takeEvery('SET_STATE', myFn)
}

run(mySaga)

store.dispatch({type: 'SET_STATE', counter: 0})
```